# How to join counts from enumerate() in python?

Tags: python, replace, enumerate

How can I join double/triple/etc.-digit counts from enumerate() to form a single string? I want to iterate through a list of US 5-digit zipcodes in order that a new list is formed containing a reference url rewritten with each zipcode in the list:

```
# "70048" is the original zip
ref_url = "https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=70048&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05" 
indices = []
zip_list = # A list of zipcodes

for c, v in enumerate(ref_url):
    if v.isdigit():
        index = ''.join(str(c))
        indices += index
        if len(indices) == 5:
            break
```

`indices` would allow me to then `.replace` the exact spot (the old zipcode) I need with the next `zip` by doing `ref_url.replace(ref_url[indices[0]]:ref_url[indices[-1]], zip)` (with a separate loop). Why won't `.join(c)` lead to multi-digit `c`'s joining to get a proper index?

Comment: FYI, `''.join(str(c))` is 100% pointless; it's equivalent to just `str(c)` (which you then pointlessly split into characters only to combine them back into a new `str` with the same value as `str(c)`). I have no idea what you're trying to do here, but I'm fairly sure it makes no sense.

Comment: Can you provide some sample values for `zip_list` that shows what values you expect there? Postal codes vary greatly between countries and it may not be obvious to readers how they can vary, don't assume users of SO all live in the US (which the use of "zipcode" may imply). (Postal codes I've lived in include "4101", "2595 BT" and "10179")  The solution could be affected (for example having to deal with spaces would)

Comment: Don't use enumerate.  If the URLs all look like that, then just do `i = url.find(`q=')`, and fetch `url[i+2:i+7]`.  Or, you could use a regular expression to search non-digit followed by 5 digits followed by a non-digit.

Comment: Python comes with a URL parser module, `urllib.parse`, which is almost certainly going to be better than writing your own code to do this.

Comment: @Grismar I've edited the question to specify.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks, I think this module might be the easiest fix.

Comment: What do you mean by "joining" the counts, and why it is relevant that they come "from enumerate"? What is the code actually supposed to do? What is `indices` and where is it defined? Please read [mre] and show an exact possible input and **exactly** what the output should be as a result.

Comment: I [edit]ed the question to [remove noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) - please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. However, I still cannot understand the question, nor follow your reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward way to find the zip and replace it with each of multiple other zips would be to use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and the [`span()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.span) method of the [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) object it returns:

```py
ref_url = "https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=70048&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05"
import re
m = re.search(r'q=\d{5}', ref_url)
zip_list = ['12345','98765', '10101', '98989'] # A list of zipcodes
pref, suff = ref_url[:m.span()[0] + len('q=')], ref_url[m.span()[1]:]
for z in zip_list:
    print(pref + z + suff)
```

Output:

```
https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=12345&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05
https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=98765&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05
https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=10101&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05
https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=98989&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05
```

Alternatively, a light-touch rewrite of the code in your question to get the desired behavior is:

```py
ref_url = "https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=70048&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05" 
indices = []
for c, v in enumerate(ref_url):
    if v.isdigit():
        indices += [c]
        if len(indices) == 5:
            break
zip_list = ['12345','98765', '10101', '98989'] # A list of zipcodes
pref, suff = ref_url[:indices[0]], ref_url[indices[-1]:]
for z in zip_list:
    print(pref + z + suff)
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your clarification regarding asterisks. The regex containing `q=\d{5}` will match the string `q=` followed by exactly 5 digits (`\d`). The `pref` variable takes a substring from the beginning of `ref_url` that adds back the length of `q=` to ensure that `pref` and `suff` contain all characters except the 5 digits of the original zip code.

Answer (score 0):

Although the other answer was already accepted, there's far simpler solutions that seem cleaner. Like this trivial one:

```
ref_url = "https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q={zip}&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05" 

zip_list = ['12345','98765', '10101', '98989']
for z in zip_list:
    print(ref_url.format(zip=z))
```

Or, if you have to work with a reference URL that already has a zipcode in there, using regex:

```
import re

ref_url = "https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=70048&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05"

zip_list = ['12345','98765', '10101', '98989']
for z in zip_list:
    print(re.sub('(?<=\?q=)\d+', z, ref_url))
```

Both of these solutions meet the needs of the question and avoid a lot of 'manual labour' in your code that serves little purpose.

Both these examples produce identical output:

```
https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=12345&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05
https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=98765&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05
https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=10101&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05
https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=98989&tid=ACSDP5Y2020.DP05
```